# how to remove a product from a specific web site, using a template whose fields are required to perform the action

Tags: product, upgrade, catalog, delete, websites

Currently I want to delete specific products from a website massively as it is a huge list of SKUs so I want to do it through a template and I have the first 2 fields but I need a third one what would be this one?

[image: these are the fields I have]

I need to remove the hook from this area.

[image]